# How to create a virtual font?

Tags: fonts, hyphenation

In his answer to the question [Replace hyphenation character by a backwards arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9358/replace-hyphenation-character-by-a-backwards-arrow/9424#9424), Hendrik Vogt writes:

> If you come into a situation where you want your hyphenchar to be
>   something like `\hookleftarrow`, and Philipp's answer does *not* help,
>   then there's still the option to create a virtual font. By this you
>   can circumvent both the problems that `\hookleftarrow` is from a
>   different font and that it's not a single character. It's not as hard
>   as it might sound: If you need this, I can fill in the details.

I would like to know these "details" and a solution to this problem in particular.

Comment: The [UK TUG FAQ has a page on virtual fonts](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=virtualfonts). There many other helpful resources. If you have access to a copy of Alan Hoenig's book "TeX Unbound: LaTeX & TeX strategies for fonts, graphics, and more" the chapter on "Virtual Fonts, Virtuous Fonts" is a good introduction to the topic, if now getting rather dated (published 1998). [Amazon have a Look-inside facility for the book](http://www.amazon.com/TeX-Unbound-LaTeX-Strategies-Graphics/dp/019509686X); there was a [review in TUGboat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb19-2/tb59revh.pdf).

Comment: Do you have a specific group of fonts in mind you'd like to convert to virtual fonts, or do you want to have instructions for all possible fonts?

Comment: Another way to create virtual fonts is to use something like `fontinst`. If you want to mix numbers of glyphs from different fonts (perhaps including fonts for which you don't have TFMs or map fragments or FD files etc.), then `fontinst` can handle much of the nitty gritty details humans suck at and computers excel at. You can also fake fonts this way (oblique, small caps etc.) although obviously I wouldn't know anything about that kind of typographically dubious shenanigans .

Comment: Note that `fontinst` would be insane overkill for the type of use mentioned in the question. However, lest this become the 'how to make a virtual font' question (which it shouldn't as it doesn't ask that), this is probably worth noting.

Comment: The Font Installation Guide is the best introduction to the topic I've come across and is part of standard TeX distributions. (But I've never managed to get a look at a copy of AH's book, so it may be superior. Nonetheless, The Font Installation Guide is certainly a comprehensive introduction. I have no programming knowledge and know nothing about the innards of TeX or LaTeX. Hence, if I could use the guilde to install fonts from scratch and support fancy swashes and ligatures, anybody can do it.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do the following steps to create a virtual font with the hookleftarrow in it. First choose a font which you want as a base font. In this example, I take a helvetica clone (phvr8r). Create the property list format from that font and put the result into a file that will be used as a template for our virtual font property list file (vpl):

```
tftopl phvr8r.tfm > myfont.vpl
```

Now edit this file and add the following lines at the beginning of the vpl file:

```
(MAPFONT D 0 (FONTNAME phvr8r))
(MAPFONT D 1 (FONTNAME cmmi10))
(MAPFONT D 2 (FONTNAME cmsy10))
```

This loads `phvr8r` (our base font), and both math fonts needed for the hookleftarrow. Now we want to replace the hyphen of the font, so look up entry 055 `(CHARACTER O 55` and replace this entry with

```
(CHARACTER O 55
   (CHARWD R 0.8)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 2)
      (SETCHAR O 040)
      (MOVELEFT R 0.200)
      (SELECTFONT D 1)
      (SETCHAR O 055)
      )
   )
```

We place character (octal) 040 from font #2 and move left a bit and place character 055 from font 1. Now create a virtual font (this is a `vp`and a `tfm` file) from the property list:

```
vptovf myfont
```

Now your font is ready to use (put it in a directory where TeX can find it - I used the current working directory). This is my plain TeX test file:

```
 \font\myfont=myfont
 \hsize 4in
 \myfont
 A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet
 mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the
 charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.
 I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil
 existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single
 stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.
 \bye
```

Comment: @Michel: I now merged your registered and unregistered account together, so you receive ownership of this question again. You can now up-vote and accept an answer.

Answer (score 12):

Patrick's procedure works well indeed. However it's a bit more complicated to persuade LaTeX to use the new font. Here is a hack, I'll use the same font as example.

```
mv phvr8r.tfm xphvr8r.tfm
tftopl xphvr8r.tfm > phvr8r.vpl
```

Now edit the `.vpl` file as Patrick suggests, but changing

```
(MAPFONT D 0 (FONTNAME phvr8r)) -> (MAPFONT D 0 (FONTNAME xphvr8r))
```

Then run

```
vpltovf phvr8r.vpl
```

If we now write this test file in the same directory

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapline{+xphvr8r NimbusSanL-Regu " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <uhvr8a.pfb}

\setlenght{\textwidth}{4in}

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont

 A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet
 mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the
 charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.
 I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil
 existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single
 stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.

\end{document}
```

we'll get the same output. The argument of `\pdfmapline` can be obtained by looking for `phvr8r` in `pdftex.map`, by copying the relevant line and adding `+x` in front of it.

This works because TeX looks first in the current directory for files. Doing this way makes it possible to use the standard font description files for the `phv` family. In case the newly created virtual font must be used for bigger projects, it's better to define a new font family name and build new font description files.