# Replace cmtt10 \char32 (visible cup space) with something more gentle?

Tags: symbols, typewriter

I'm typesetting source code, and I want to replace cmtt10's `\char32` with something easier on the eyes.  I came up with something that I like, but I'm not pleased with the implementation.  Here's how it looks...  Top is standard cup space; bottom is my replacement version:

[image: sample]

Is there a simpler or cleaner way to do what I did?  (1) I'm having to include the `tipa` package for `\textbottomtiebar`.  (2) It just so happens, for some reason that seems bizarre to me, that package `aeguill` modifies this bottom tie bar to make it wider, which happens to be just what I want.  But that combination feels kludgey and fragile to me.

As to the core of the implementation, it uses `\ooalign`, `\hss`, and `\hphantom` to center a tiny bottom tie within the standard width of a space character:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tipa} % For \textbottomtiebar
\usepackage[lm]{aeguill} % For some reason, widens the bottom tie

\newcommand{\visp}{%  Acronym for "VIsible SPace"
  \ooalign{%
    \relax\cr%
    \hss{\tiny\textbottomtiebar{\ }}\hss\cr%
    \hphantom{~}\cr%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\texttt{Hello,{\char32}world!{\char32}{\char32}I{\char32}am{\char32}a{\char32}string.} ~~~ $\backslash$char32
\vskip 1em
\texttt{Hello,{\visp}world!{\visp}{\visp}I{\visp}am{\visp}a{\visp}string.} ~~~ $\backslash$visp

\end{document}
```

For me, this is a big improvement over `\char32`, and I'd be perfectly happy replacing `\char32` with this, but I doubt it's possible due to the way TeX's innards work.  So I gave it the name `\visp` in my style preamble.

Comment: You can always create a virtual font and replace char 32 with a reference to the glyph from the other font. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25852/243

Comment: Do you now want a nicer/better implementation or help exchanging the char32 with your macro? The latter can be done by making the space active.

Comment: @MartinScharrer — Mostly concerned with simplifying the underlying implementation, but overriding char32 is definitely a bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to patch the `verbatim*` environment and the `\verb*` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T3,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[lm]{aeguill} % is it really needed?

\newcommand{\visp}{%
  \makebox[.5em]{\vphantom{Xg}\raisebox{-\height}{\smash{\tiny
    \fontencoding{T3}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\textbottomtiebar}}}}

\makeatletter
\def\@space@visp{\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\visp}
\pretocmd\@sverb{\catcode`\ =\active\@space@visp}{}{}
\global\@namedef{verbatim*}{\@verbatim\catcode`\ =\active\@space@visp\@sxverbatim}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim*}
abc def ghi
\end{verbatim*}

\verb*|abc def|

\end{document}
```

There's no reason to load `tipa`, as declaring the T3 encoding is sufficient.

[image]

It's quite strange to use the `aeguill` package nowadays, as loading the  T1 encoding instead of OT1 is sufficient to get good guillemets with `<<guillemets>>`.

Comment: Nice, very nice, @egreg. I worked this back into my earlier solution and am quite happy that I need neither `aeguill` nor `tipa` to make this work. Thank you. Questions: (1) Why `\makebox[.5em]`? It does appear that `cmtt10` characters are exactly .5em wide, but having that be hard-coded seems like an empirical derivation to me, which is why I was shooting for something with `\hphantom{~}`. (2) I really like the `\vphantom{Xg}` trick, but does it actually make a difference here? Seems not to when I use `\ooalign` for this. In any case, thank you once again. I have more than enough to go on.

Comment: \hphantom{~} is as hard-coded as `0.5em`; being in a fixed width font context, you can use ``\fontcharwd\font`A`` instead.

Comment: [@egreg] Whoa, ok, so using `\hphantom{~}` here is actually less logically correct than picking a letter like A, even though they both happen to have the same width? I'm curious, why do you suggest ``\fontcharwd\font`A`` instead of `\hphantom{A}`?

Comment: @ToddLehman I can put ``\fontcharwd\font`A`` in the optional argument to `\makebox`, so I can avoid tricks for centering afterwards. I guess that `\widthof{A}` with the `calc` package would do the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the space active and use your `\visp` macro. You can define a macro like `\enablevisp` which switches this on for the rest of the current group.

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\ =\active%
\newcommand{\enablevisp}{%
\ttfamily%
\catcode`\ =\active%
\def {\visp}%
}%
\endgroup%
```

This can be used like:

```
{\enablevisp{}Hello world! How are you?}
```

It is also possible to define a `\textvisp` macro:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\textvisp}{%
   \begingroup
   \enablevisp
   \@textvisp
}
\def\@textvisp#1{%
   #1%
   \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

which then can be used like:

```
\textvisp{Hello world! How are you?}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I found two other alternatives to `\textbottomtiebar`. One is `\textvisiblespace` and the other is `\smile`. The latter is a math-mode glyph which was too large to start with so I shrunk it using `\scalebox`.

I cleaned up the `\textbottomtiebar` solution thanks to @egreg's tips, and came up with three variants, shown below with `\char32`:

[image]

I want to share the code for these here in case anyone else finds them useful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}  % Only needed for the \smile version
\usepackage[T3,OT1]{fontenc}  % Only needed for the \textbottomtiebar version

% (a) \char32 version
\newcommand{\vispa}{%
  \char32%
}

% (b) \textvisiblespace version
\newcommand{\vispb}{%
  \ooalign{%
    \relax\cr%
    \noalign{\vskip.2ex}%
    \textvisiblespace\cr%
    \noalign{\vskip-.2ex}%
    \hphantom{~}\cr%   Width of a space character
    \vphantom{Xg}\cr%  Height of X, depth of g
  }%
}

% (c) \textbottomtiebar version
\newcommand{\vispc}{%
  \ooalign{%
    \relax\cr%
    \hss\smash{\tiny\fontencoding{T3}\fontfamily{cmr}%
               \selectfont\textbottomtiebar}\hss\cr%
    \hphantom{~}\cr%   Width of a space character
    \vphantom{Xg}\cr%  Height of X, depth of g
  }%
}

% (d) \smile version
\newcommand{\vispd}{%
  \ooalign{%
    \relax\cr%
    \noalign{\vskip.5ex}%
    \hss\scalebox{.4}{$\smile$}\hss\cr%
    \noalign{\vskip-.5ex}%
    \hphantom{~}\cr%   Width of a space character
    \vphantom{Xg}\cr%  Height of X, depth of g
  }%
}

% Just for demonstration and testing
\newcommand{\testvisp}[2]{%
  ``\texttt{abc{#1}def{#1#1#1#1}ghi}''%
  \quad{\tiny$\backslash$#2}\par
}

\begin{document}
\testvisp{\vispa}{char32}
\testvisp{\vispb}{textvisiblespace}
\testvisp{\vispc}{textbottomtiebar}
\testvisp{\vispd}{smile}
\end{document}
```