# How can I construct a math alphabet with lowercase and uppercase from different predefined sets?

Tags: calligraphy, alphabet

I'm currently using the rsfs letters for caligriphic symbols. However, there is no corresponding lowercase alphabet, so I have begun to experiment with others. Is there a way that I can make it so that I may write `$\mathscr{Ker}$`, as opposed to `$\mathscr{K}\mathcal{er}$`, as I have been doing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: use XeTeX or LuaTeX and then load XITS math, it has all characters

Comment: @Herbert: you can also load the XITS math alphabets with standard LaTeX by using the [boondox](http://ctan.org/pkg/boondox) package, loading it with `\usepackage{BOONDOX-cal}`.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet: it is much more easier to replace a math alphabet with xetex or luatex

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way of doing it based on what `txfonts.sty` does for its `\varmathbb` alphabet. As you didn't give any detail, I've supposed the lowercase alphabet comes from the Chancery font (codename `pzc`). Of course, the two don't go at all well together as the bad spacing in Ker shows, so you'll have to adapt the code to your needs:

[image: result of the code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mathscrUC}{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}  % Formal Script for uppercase
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathscrLC}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{n} % Chancery for lowercase

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% code from txfonts.sty (for \varmathbb) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\mathscr}[1]{\gdef\F@ntPrefix{mathscr@char@}%
  \@EachCharacter #1\@EndEachCharacter}
\long\def\DoLongFutureLet #1#2#3#4{% 
   \def\@FutureLetDecide{#1#2\@FutureLetToken
      \def\@FutureLetNext{#3}\else
      \def\@FutureLetNext{#4}\fi\@FutureLetNext}
   \futurelet\@FutureLetToken\@FutureLetDecide}
\def\DoFutureLet #1#2#3#4{\DoLongFutureLet{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\def\@EachCharacter{\DoFutureLet{\ifx}{\@EndEachCharacter}%
   {\@EachCharacterDone}{\@PickUpTheCharacter}}
\def\m@keCharacter#1{\csname\F@ntPrefix#1\endcsname}
\def\@PickUpTheCharacter#1{\m@keCharacter{#1}\@EachCharacter}
\def\@EachCharacterDone \@EndEachCharacter{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% defining each individual symbols %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@A}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@B}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@C}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@D}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@E}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@F}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@G}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`G}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@H}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`H}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@I}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@J}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`J}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@K}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@L}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`L}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@M}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@N}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@O}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@P}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@Q}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`Q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@R}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`R}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@S}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`S}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@T}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@U}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`U}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@V}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`V}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@W}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`W}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@X}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@Y}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@Z}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`Z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@a}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`a}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@b}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`b}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@c}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`c}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@d}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`d}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@e}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`e}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@f}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`f}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@g}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`g}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@h}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`h}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@i}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`i}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@j}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`j}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@k}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`k}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@l}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`l}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@m}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@n}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@o}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`o}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@p}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`p}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@q}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@r}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`r}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@s}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`s}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@t}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`t}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@u}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`u}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@v}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`v}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@w}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`w}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@x}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`x}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@y}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@z}{\mathord}{mathscrLC}{`z}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMm}$

$\mathscr{NnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz}$

$\mathscr{Ker}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to the problem: Create a virtual font out of the given fonts and use it afterwards as a math alphabet. Here is a starter on virtual fonts: [How to create a virtual font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25852/how-to-create-a-virtual-font)