# Looking for a fancy math typeface featuring not only uppercase, but also lowercase letters

Tags: math-mode, typefaces

I'm looking for a math typeface that is "fancy" (like the AMS typefaces `\mathbb` and `\mathcal`), and which features not only upper case letters but also lower case ones. Ideally, the letters would be simple enough to draw by hand.

Comment: Very related: [How can I construct a math alphabet with lowercase and uppercase from different predefined sets?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68818/5764)

Answer (score 4):

[The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/alphfonts.html) contains a host of supported fonts you can use. Specifically it also lists [Fonts with math support](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html).