# How to Produce Specific Mathematical Representations of Letters

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Can anyone please explain how I should produce these symbols in TeX?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you load the [mathalfa](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) package with the options `cal=mt` and `scr=kp`. The former option assigns the Math Time Pro calligraphic font face to `\mathcal` -- note, though, that the mtpro2 package isn't free of charge -- and the KP fonts script font face to `\mathscr`.

Do check out pp. 8 and 9 of the user guide of the `mathalfa` package for other possible choices for `\mathscr`.

The match between the first letter in the OP's screenshot and `\mathcal{B}` would appear to be perfect. The second letter in the OP's screenshot seems to be halfway between `\mathscr{B}` and `\bm{\mathscr{B}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=mt,scr=kp]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{B} \quad \mathscr{B} \quad \bm{\mathscr{B}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking like an example the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68818/how-can-i-construct-a-math-alphabet-with-lowercase-and-uppercase-from-different) of @Philippe Goutet, where where I have made some small changes, considering also the answer of @Mico, you can define your **B** calligraphic letters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[cal=mt]{mathalfa}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mathscrUC}{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}
%%%% from the answer and http://ctan.epst-tlemcen.dz/tex-archive/fonts/txfonts/input/txfonts.sty
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\mathscr}[1]{\gdef\F@ntPrefix{mathscr@char@}%
  \@EachCharacter #1\@EndEachCharacter}
\long\def\DoLongFutureLet #1#2#3#4{% 
   \def\@FutureLetDecide{#1#2\@FutureLetToken
      \def\@FutureLetNext{#3}\else
      \def\@FutureLetNext{#4}\fi\@FutureLetNext}
   \futurelet\@FutureLetToken\@FutureLetDecide}
\def\DoFutureLet #1#2#3#4{\DoLongFutureLet{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\def\@EachCharacter{\DoFutureLet{\ifx}{\@EndEachCharacter}%
   {\@EachCharacterDone}{\@PickUpTheCharacter}}
\def\m@keCharacter#1{\csname\F@ntPrefix#1\endcsname}
\def\@PickUpTheCharacter#1{\m@keCharacter{#1}\@EachCharacter}
\def\@EachCharacterDone \@EndEachCharacter{}
% It has been declared only the letter B. 
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathscr@char@B}{\mathord}{mathscrUC}{`B}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{B}, \mathscr{B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]