# Ugly spacings with \mathcal font

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, mathcal, horizontal

I hate the horizontal spacings with letters from the \mathcal font.  Is there a way to fix them?  Here's a MWE showing the ugliness:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    dx_{\smash{\, \mathcal{AB}}}^{\mu} + dx_{\smash{\, \mathcal{BC}}}^{\mu} + dx_{\smash{\, \mathcal{CD}}}^{\mu} + dx_{\smash{\, \mathcal{DA}}}^{\mu} \ne 0.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

As the preview is showing, the A and D letters are getting some relatively large space between them, while A and B are glued together.  I find this very ugly.  Is there a way to make a nice consistent (i.e. uniform) spacing between each of these letters?

I'm tempted to add some space between A and B (and also between B and C), but that would be an "hack" and wouldn't be consistent.

**Unrelated:**  I had to smash these letters and add a small space to make the indices at a consistent height with other equations, and to prevent the indices to overlap.

Comment: You say doing doing the spacing manually would be a "hack", but you are already doing this when you write `\,` in the subscripts, so the odd `\!` is not much extra for that level of control over the spacing.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to kern characters in math mode is using `\mkern`.  If you want to have this done automatically you will have to create a [virtual font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25852/how-to-create-a-virtual-font).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
    dx_{\mathcal{AB}}^{\mu}
    + dx_{\mathcal{BC}}^{\mu}
    + dx_{\mathcal{C\mkern-1mu D}}^{\mu}
    + dx_{\mathcal{D\mkern-2mu A}}^{\mu}
    \ne 0.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

- Load `unicode-math` and use an OpenType font
- Load `unicode-math` and load a different calligraphic font with `\setmathfont[range=cal,...`
- Load a different 8-bit `\mathcal` alphabet with `mathalpha`
- Manually adjust the kerning with `\mkern` commands (see answer by Henri Menke).

Answer (score 1):

Edit by correct comment of the user @ Henri Menke.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
dx_{\mathcal{AB}}^{\mu} + dx_{\mathcal{BC}}^{\mu} + dx_{\mathcal{C\mkern-1mu D}}^{\mu} + dx_{\mathcal{D\mkern-2mu A}}^{\mu} \ne 0.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should use `\mkern` instead of `\hspace`, e.g. `\mathcal{C\mkern-1mu D}` and `\mathcal{D\mkern-2mu A}`.  And of course you should remove all the document options and packages that are not actually needed for this example, which is all of them in this case.

Comment: @HenriMenke Hi, and excuse me again. I have forgotten that in math mode I must use `\mkern`. Thank you very much for your comment that I have appreciated.