# Allow line break, but without inserting a dash

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, punctuation

I have a sentence that contains a number of long dataset names. I would like to allow LaTeX to break these names at certain positions that I would like to specify somehow just like I can use `\-` to allow a word break with hyphenation. But: I would like LaTeX **not** to insert a dash (which could be mistaken as belonging to the dataset name). How can I do this?

(Something similar is realized in the `url` package so I guess I could just read that code :) I would not like to use the `url` package here to be able to make a syntactical (and typographic) difference between urls and datset names.)

Comment: This may also be of interest: [Replace hyphenation character by a backwards arrow](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9358/replace-hyphenation-character-by-a-backwards-arrow)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You could insert `\allowbreak` whereever a break without hyphen shall be allowed, such as

```
long\allowbreak word
```

Comment: Is there a way to allow line breaks only at the specified positions? Otherwise LaTeX will often prefer to still add hyphens and break at other positions. (This happens When using e.g. `hyphenat` for automatic hyphenation.)

Comment: You can use `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` together with `\allowbreak`.

Comment: Also extremely useful if one has a text-segment that goes like WORD/WORD, where the ideal breaking point would be »/«

Comment: This worked great for my use case: `\texttt{sysctl net.\allowbreak ipv6.\allowbreak conf.\allowbreak interface.\allowbreak accept\_dad\allowbreak =\allowbreak 0}`.

Answer (score 37):

In addition to Stefan’s answer:

You can also write `long""word`, but this is a `babel`-shortcut (as most of the following). As Herbert pointed out these shortcuts are language specific. The list is taken form a german home page and are in the german section of `babels` manual.

`-` hyphen sign, no others in this word (`hy-phenation` > hy-|phenation)
`"=` hypen sign that allows other breaks (`h"=yphenation` > h-|y|phen|a|tion)
`"~` hyphen sign without line break (`hy"~phenation` > hy-phenation)
`\-` possible hyphenation with sign (`h\-yphenation` > h|y|phen|a|tion)
`""` possible hyphenation without sign (`(super"~)""hyphenation` > (super-)*hy|pen|a|tion)
`"|` break ligature and allow hyphenation

*[( `code` > output); the pipe indicates possible line break with hyphen sign; asterisk indicates possible line break without sign.]*

Source: [This](http://homepage.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/georg.verweyen/silbentrennung.html) german homepage.

Comment: Seems to be `babel` specific, yes.

Comment: @Tobi: not only babel specific, also language specific

Comment: @Herbert: Oh you’re right. I added this to my post.

Comment: As far as I can tell. `"~` forbids hyphenation in the rest of the word.

Comment: @Raphael: Thanks. I’m not sure about that, can’t find anything in the `babel` manual, but I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Any idea how to enable `"=` with babel-english?

Comment: @koppor: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321066/4918 ;-)

Answer (score 13):

it is also possible to allow hyphenation on Characters

```
\documentclass{article}                 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} 
\textwidth=10cm% only for demo
\DeclareUrlCommand\Code{\urlstyle{rm}}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks  
\do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k
\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v
\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z
\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K
\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V
\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}
\begin{document}            
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
some very long text before the hyphenated code
\Code{someverylongtextbeforethehyphenatedcode}

some very long text before the hyphenated code
\Code{some-long-command-name-with-a-lot-of-dases}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, because it's automatic and does not add hyphens. But what if I have e.g. `longtextthatdoesnothavecharactersurlbreaksatatanypositionbutneedstobebroken` -- I'd need to indicate how (where) to break this, but the `\Code` enviroment will print any commands in verbatim mode...

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: OK, that's certainly one solution. Although I had hoped for something more along the lines of `\allowbreak` or `\-`... Because like this it's still not possible to specify where exactly LaTeX should break the line.

Answer (score 12):

I've had good results with

```
\linebreak[X]
```

Where `X` can be anything from 0 to 4. Zero means "if you really want, you can break the line here", while four means "break the line here, always".

To allow for long word breaking, you can insert it like this:

```
verylongword\linebreak[0]{}thatshouldbebroken
```

I'm not sure if it does not require specific packages though.

Answer (score 7):

From The TeXbook:

```
\discretionary{<pre-break text>}{<post-break text>}{<no-break text>}
```

You could try something like:

```
\newcommand{\sep}{\discretionary{}{}{}}
\newcommand{\datasetname}{My\sep long\sep data\sep set\sep name}
```

Answer (score 6):

@fuenfundachzig: Since you're familiar with the `url` package, you may want to try the following: Include the instructions `\usepackage{url}` and `\urlstyle={same}` in the preamble (instructing the url package to use the main text font for URLs), and then enclose the words that you'd like to be allow broken up inside `\url{...}` commands. In my experience, this works very well most of the time, but it's not 100% foolproof (narrensicher?), naturally.

Comment: Oops, just noticed that this answer is a near-perfect duplicate of the one posted by Herbert! Sorry.

Comment: You don't need to write `@fuenfundachtzig` here, as the question asker, he or she will automatically be notified of your answer, just like you as the answerer ("post owner") will be notified of this comment of mine without me using the `@...`. I don't think it's a problem that your answer is very similar to Herbert's. You could edit your answer to highlight what's different (and maybe better) about your solution. If the differences are really tiny, you could delete your answer and add a comment to Herbert's answer. And finally, _foolproof_ is a good translation of _narrensicher_ `:)`.

Answer (score 6):

A possibly “gentle” solution is to input your long words with spaces where the line breaks are allowed. The separator is customizable, here I added an optional argument for changing it at will.

I also disabled hyphenation by setting a language with no patterns; this is not necessary if a monospaced font is uses, as usually monospaced fonts disable hyphenation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Code}{ O{~} m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 } { \allowbreak }
  \language\csname l@nohyphenation\endcsname % or \language255
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\parbox{10cm}{
some very long text before the hyphenated code
\Code{some very long text before thehyphenated code}

some very long text before the hyphenated code
\Code[-]{some-long-command-name-with-a-lot-of-dashes}
}

\bigskip

\parbox{3cm}{
\Code{some very long text before thehyphenated code}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use pakage seqsplit,
in main text: \seqsplit{qervnjksnvdjsn},
this means it can linebreak between every singal character,
without dash or hyphen sign.
Sorry for bad English.
：）