# How to automatically break "a long word with underscore" in a cell of table, using longtabu package?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable

I use `longtabu` package for creating tables, because the table can be very long (several pages) and i need automatic linebreak(or wordbreak) if the sentence(or a single word) in certain cell is too long.

In most cases, `longtabu` works well for my purpose. But, if a long word contains underscore, for example, `AAA_BB_CCC_D_EEEEEE_FFF_GGGGG_HHHHHH` (I replace `_` as `\\_` in latex), then the word can not be linebreaked and it cross out of the border of the cell to the next cell.

How can `longtabu` automatically break a long word with underscore? I want the very long word can automatically fit the length of a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some potential breaking points to the long word by adding `\-` (if you want a hyphen when breaking} or `\allowbreak` (if you don't).

Examples

```
\fbox{\parbox[b]{5cm}{AAA\_BB\_CCC\_D\_EEE\-EEE\_FFF\_GGGGG\_HHHHHH}}
\fbox{\parbox[b]{5cm}{AAA\_BB\_CCC\_D\_EEEEEE\allowbreak \_FFF\_GGGGG\_HHHHHH}}
```

resulting in

[image]

more information at [*this related question*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26174/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at the [hyphenat package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat/) which redefines the underscore \_ so that hyphenation can automatically occur. This adds a hyphen at the end of the line. This has the advantage that you don't have to manually add \- in every word with an underscore.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox[b]{5cm}{AAA\_BB\_CCC\_D\_EEEEEE\_FFF\_GGGGG\_HHHHHH}}
\end{document}
```