# Custom command exceeds my textwidth

Tags: fonts, margins

I have a problem I do not know how to handle:

I need to include some small words of code - these can sometimes be longer names of something.
To display this is a name of a code piece, I've made a small command, `\code{...}` which wraps the `...` in a special font.

But when the `...` gets too long, the text exceeds my margins of the page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % Just to show the frames

%A font for code
\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont #1}}

\begin{document}
This is a longer line -- notice what happens now at the end: \code{OfThisLongPeiceOfText}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any suggestions to how I can fix this?
Forcing a  `\\` when I see it gives me problems or split it up with `\code{firstPart}\code{SecondPart}` ?

Comment: you need to say what you want to happen, choices are break before the code, leaving the line short, break before the code stretching the line out, or allowing the code to break with, or without hyphenation.

Comment: Lets say I want it to break without hyphenation. Do you have a suggestion of how it could be done?

Comment: We are looking for something like \code{OfThisLong\allowbreak PeiceOfText} but without the space...

Comment: Try this one, hope it helps:
`\newcommand{\code}[1]{\@tfor\@temp:=#1\do{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\@temp}\allowbreak}}`

Comment: Does not compile, @SunilkumarKS. `` LaTeX Error: Command \ unavailable in encoding OT1. [...ow at the end: \code{OfThisLongPeiceOfText}]``. It looks like it does not recognize the ``\allowbreak``

Comment: Looks strange, this is my code:

`\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\@tfor\@temp:=#1\do{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\@temp}\allowbreak}}

\begin{document}
This is a longer line -- notice what happens now at the end: 
\code{OfThsLongPeiceOfText}

\end{document}`

Comment: What does work is this suggestion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26177/31636. But it removes the font...

Comment: If the problem persists, you might try with: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: It persists - even with ``T1``: http://imgur.com/YW35Qen. 
Is it my compiler?

Comment: perhaps you want this automatic breaking for camel case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66593/automatic-camel-case-breaking/66603#66603

Comment: That is a very good suggestion, @DavidCarlisle - but it's not enough: http://i.imgur.com/ZJk6JpL.png - but better than nothing!

Comment: Strange to see `Undefined control sequence` error for `\code` in http://imgur.com/YW35Qen!

Comment: Your camels need more humps:-) If you add \sloppy before the paragraph the white space will stretch to allow breaking

Comment: I'm not a big fan of ``\sloppy`` - it makes the spaces way too big.

Answer (score 2):

in such cases use:

```
\begin{sloppypar}
This is a longer line -- notice what happens now at the end: \code{OfThisLongPeiceOfText}
\end{sloppypar}
```

and if you do not like `\sloppypar` use:

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{showframe} % Just to show the frames
\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\ttfamily#1}}
```

Or use the german shortcuts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
\usepackage{showframe} % Just to show the frames
\newcommand\code[1]{{\ttfamily#1}}


\begin{document}
This is a longer line -- notice what happens now at the end: \code{OfThis""Long""Peice""OfText}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It could seem like ``sloppybar`` does the same as ``seqsplit``. Can you implement this as a ``\command`` without the word is moved to a new line?

``beramono`` overrides the ``\ttfamily``?

Comment: Should  `OfThisLongPeiceOfText` be hyphenated or not. And yes, `beramono` defines a new monospace font.

Comment: It should not be.

Comment: Then use `\newcommand\code[1]{{\mbox{\ttfamily#1}}}` and `sloppypar` or set the paragraph with `\RaggedRight` (package `ragged2e`) or insert a `\newline` before `\code`

Comment: I really want the ``\code`` word to be split up. ``sloppypar`` makes the whole line have huge spaces in it, which does not look good.
``\RaggedRight`` does not help, since it moves everything down, and ``\newline`` will do the same.

Comment: You can use `babel` and the german shortcuts and then `\codeOf""ThisLong""PeiceOfText}` Then it can be hyphenated at the `""` without a hyphen.

Comment: I tried those - I cannot get it to work. Do you have an MWE?

Comment: see edited answer

Answer (score 1):

One way (not the best) is splitting it with the `seqsplit` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{seqsplit}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont \seqsplit{#1}}}

\begin{document}
This is a longer line -- notice what happens now at the end: \code{OfThsLongPeiceOfText} 
\end{document}
```

Will give this:
[image]

---

But there exists solutions with *CamelCase* splitting (shamelessly taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66603/31636 as mentioned by @DavidCarlisle), which works most of the time:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe} 

\showhyphens{createUnspecifiedNodeErrorMarker}

\makeatletter
\def\code{\leavevmode\begingroup
\let\ifcase\iftrue
\def\or##1{%
  \catcode`##1\active\uccode`\~`##1\uppercase{%
    \def~{\egroup\penalty2\hbox\bgroup\string##1}}}%
\@Alph{}%
\@code}

\def\@code#1{\textbf{\hbox\bgroup#1\egroup}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a longer line -- notice what happens now at the end: \code{OfThisLongPeiceOfText} 
\code{OfThisLongPeiceOfText} 
\code{OfThisLongPeiceOfText} 
\code{OfThisLongPeiceOfText} 
\code{OfThisLongPeiceOfText} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

But not always:

[image: text]