# Babel: Add german language shorthands

Tags: babel, languages, hyphenation, shorthands

I want to use the German language shorthands provided by babel with other languages; the main language of the document is German.

In following MWE the shorthands `"=` and `/""` don't work when the English language is selected; uncommenting `\useshorthands{"}` doesn't have any effect.

I tried this with `pdflatex` of TeXLive 2014 and 2016.

(Reversing the order of the languages in the option list of babel has the desired effect, but I want to have German as the main language)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
%\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{document}
erster/""zweiter Teil \\
Bindestrich"=Wort

\selectlanguage{english}

first/""second part\\
Hyphen"=Word

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
erster/""zweiter Teil\\
Bindestrich"=Wort
\end{document}
```

[image: output of MWE]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works for me with

```
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}\useshorthands{"}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}\useshorthands{"}}

\begin{document}
erster/""zweiter Teil \\
Bindestrich"=Wort

\selectlanguage{english}

first/""second part\\
Hyphen"=Word

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
erster/""zweiter Teil\\
Bindestrich"=Wort
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this drove me crazy as other posts indicate that my MWE indeed should work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27198

Answer (score 9):

You can use the star version of \useshorthands to keep it active in all languages:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\useshorthands*{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{document}
erster/""zweiter Teil \\
Bindestrich"=Wort

\selectlanguage{english}

first/""second part\\
Hyphen"=Word

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
erster/""zweiter Teil\\
Bindestrich"=Wort
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, this works -- i missed the starred version. Shame that I can't accept two answers :-(  Thanks!