# line height varies with wrapping text

Tags: line-breaking, line-spacing

I was trying to create a new title page for uni project.
For that I took an [online template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/vertical-line-title-page) and changed the text.

The problem now is, that the title wraps and has different line height in some lines.

[image: rendered pdf result]

Produced by this latex MVP

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}

        \rule{1pt}{\textheight}
        \hspace{0.05\textwidth}
        \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{
            \raggedright

            {\Huge\bfseries Entwicklung einer agentenbasierten Simulationsplattform mithilfe des JavaScript Ökosystems, am Beispiel einer Verkehrssimulation.}\\[2\baselineskip]
            {\large\textit{Subtitle}}\\[4\baselineskip]
            {\Large\textsc{Name}}

            \vspace{0.25\textheight}

            {\noindent Organization}\\[\baselineskip]
        }

    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Can I force a consistent line height?

And one additional question, can I reenable latex automatic word breaking, so it better utilizes the available space?

Comment: First question is [fontsize - Inconsistent line spacing - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36454/inconsistent-line-spacing), second question is... just remove the raggedright, you get what you ask for.

Comment: [`ragged2e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e?lang=en) offers `\RaggedRight`, which will still allow hyphenation. Much better than `\raggedright`, in my opinion.

Comment: While the font size question has already been addressed by the linked question, the width allowed for this text is too narrow to look decent by just removing the raggedright.  A "middle" approach is to use the package `ragged2e` and specify '\Raggecright`, which doesn't suppress hyphenation but does keep word spaces at their "natural" width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `\\[ ]` as an inter-paragraph spacing, typeset proper paragraphs, ending them *before* changing the type size. And use `ragged2e` and a proper language set-up:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}

        \rule{1pt}{\textheight}
        \hspace{0.05\textwidth}
        \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{
            \RaggedRight

            {\Huge\bfseries Entwicklung einer agentenbasierten Simulationsplattform mithilfe des JavaScript Ökosystems, am Beispiel einer Verkehrssimulation.
            \par}
            \bigskip
            {\large\textit{Subtitle}\par}
            \bigskip
            {\Large\textsc{Name}\par}

            \vspace{0.25\textheight}

            {\noindent Organization}
            \bigskip
        }

    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from the snippet above]

(well, JavaScript hyphenation should be fixed, of course)...

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked and I got an idea why it didn't before. 

Just two more questions, if it is ok with you:

1. Is there a way to hint or force a line break in a paragraph, so I could fix the JavaScript word wrap?
2. Can I configure the line height, to make the title a little bit more compact?

Comment: The 1. is easy, add `\hyphenation{Java-Script}` (choose the splitting point) or `\hyphenation{JavaScript}` (no split) in the preamble. For 2: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48743/38080

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :) I had found this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26191/268858 in the meantime, which is nice because it is not as verbose.