# Getting a virtual font to work in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

In a quest for greater understanding of all thing LaTeX, I've been playing around with virtual fonts (eg. [replacing a hyphenation character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9358/replace-hyphenation-character-by-a-backwards-arrow) and [How to create a virtual font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25852/how-to-create-a-virtual-font)). However, I can't get LaTeX to recognize my new TFM file and I think the problem lies with my lack of understanding of the `\pdfmapline` command.

Here are the steps I took:

Copied a known working font from my tex directory:

```
cp /usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm .
```

Created a human-readable format:

```
tftopl cmb10 cmb10
```

Edited `cmb10.pl` and saved the new file to `foobar.vpl`. In this case I've mapped the letter b->a just to see if what I've done had some effect (see sec. 6 [here](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/info/virtualfontshowto/virtualfontshowto.txt)). Next I compiled the file to a binary format:

```
vptovf foobar.vpl
```

This creates `foobar.tfm` and `foobar.vf`. From reading around, it seems that the `\pdfmapline` looks in the local directory, so for the time being, I can leave the files where they are. Now my LaTeX document looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapline{=foorbar cmr10}

\begin{document}
aaaa bbbb aaaa
\font\test=foobar aaaa bbbb aaaa \the\font
\end{document}
```

This compiles but it does not replace any of the b's with a's.

Comment: You don't switch to your test font, you just define it (just write `\test` after the `\font .. foobar` definition. And (I am not sure about that) your `\pdfmapline` should have a `+` instead of a `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Patrick observed, you aren't switching to the new font.

Indeed, after adding

```
(MAPFONT D 0 (FONTNAME cmr10))
```

to the generated `pl` file, changing the entry for `b` into

```
(CHARACTER C b
   (CHARWD R 0.555557)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (MAP 
      (SELECTFONT D 0)
      (SETCHAR C a)
      )
   )
```

and saving as `foobar.vpl`, after `vptovf foobar`, the document

```
\pdfmapline{=foobar cmr10}

aaa bbb aaa

\font\test=foobar aaa bbb aaa

\test aaa bbb aaa


\bye
```

processed with `pdftex` will give

> aaa bbb aaa
>   aaa bbb aaa
>   aaa aaa aaa

as expected (the precise alignment is not shown here).

The command `\the\font` does nothing: it just produces the appropriate declaration for choosing the current font. If you want to print the `.tfm` file name you have to say `\fontname\font`. If we add this instruction to the three `aaa bbb aaa` lines we get

> aaa bbb aaa cmr10
>   aaa bbb aaa cmr10
>   aaa aaa aaa fooaar

(in the third line the `b` is changed into a at printing time).