# How set hyphen (divis) to specific unicode char

Tags: unicode, hyphenation

I need a specific divis / hyphen character or more than one randomly show

This code is not working at the present.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat} 
\newsavebox\leftarrowbox 
\sbox\leftarrowbox{$\leftarrow$} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\BreakableSlash}{% 
\leavevmode \prw@zbreak /% 
\discretionary{\usebox\leftarrowbox}{}{}% 
\prw@zbreak } 
\makeatother 

\begin{document} 

\parbox{40mm}{% 
\texttt{/etc\fshyp really\fshyp long\fshyp directory\fshyp name/ \blindtext}% 
} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which engine are you using?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9358/replace-hyphenation-character-by-a-backwards-arrow help?

Comment: This code not working.`\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\newsavebox\leftarrowbox
\sbox\leftarrowbox{$\leftarrow$}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\BreakableSlash}{%
  \leavevmode
  \prw@zbreak
  /%
  \discretionary{\usebox\leftarrowbox}{}{}%
  \prw@zbreak
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\parbox{40mm}{%
  \texttt{/etc\fshyp really\fshyp long\fshyp directory\fshyp name/ \blindtext}%
}
\end{document}
`

Comment: I get `/etc/really/long/←` as the first line.

Comment: this is not automatic You put `\fshyp` manulaly.